# Javascript ES6: Groupby and sum array of objects in object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to sum up all values in a nested array that belong to a group (eg. 100, 101, 102...)

I know there are some solutions floating around, but the difference is that the dictionary structure of my nested array is not {key: 100, value:0}, {key: 101, value:0}

Input:

```
{
  {key: "person1"
   values:
   [{100.0: 0, 101.0: 0, 102.0: 0, 103.0: 0, 104.0: 0},
    {100.0: 0, 101.0: 0, 102.0: 4, 103.0: 18, 104.0: 12},
    {100.0: 2, 101.0: 0, 102.0: 0, 103.0: 1, 104.0: 0},
    {100.0: 2, 101.0: 1, 102.0: 7, 103.0: 14, 104.0: 21},
    {100.0: 0, 101.0: 0, 102.0: 0, 103.0: 0, 104.0: 0}]
  }
  {key: "person2"
   values:
  [{100.0: 5, 101.0: 0, 102.0: 0, 103.0: 0, 104.0: 0},
   {100.0: 5, 101.0: 0, 102.0: 4, 103.0: 18, 104.0: 12},
   {100.0: 5, 101.0: 0, 102.0: 0, 103.0: 1, 104.0: 0},
   {100.0: 5, 101.0: 1, 102.0: 7, 103.0: 14, 104.0: 21},
   {100.0: 5, 101.0: 0, 102.0: 0, 103.0: 0, 104.0: 0}]
  }
}
```

Expected output:

```
{
[key: "person1"
 values: {100.0: 4, 101.0: 5, 102.0: 11, 103.0: 23, 104.0: 33}]
[key: "person2"
values: {100.0: 20, 101.0: 5, 102.0: 11, 103.0: 23, 104.0: 22}]
}
```

Comment: `{
  [key: "person1"` Your input is invalid. Arrays do not have key-value pairs, only values.

Comment: Is the input an array (if so it should be surrounded by `[ ]`). I suspect you want something like `[{key, values}, {key, values}]`

Comment: Your input and expected output are both not valid arrays or objects. It's hard to understand what you want, but I suspect you're looking for `map()`, or perhaps `reduce()`

Answer (score 0):

Given an array of objects, you can [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the array. Then within each iteration of `map()` [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the array of values down to the sums:

```js
let arr = [
  {
  key: "person1",
  values:[
  {100.0: 0, 101.0: 0, 102.0: 0, 103.0: 0, 104.0: 0},
  {100.0: 0, 101.0: 0, 102.0: 4, 103.0: 18, 104.0: 12},
  {100.0: 2, 101.0: 0, 102.0: 0, 103.0: 1, 104.0: 0},
  {100.0: 2, 101.0: 1, 102.0: 7, 103.0: 14, 104.0: 21},
  {100.0: 0, 101.0: 0, 102.0: 0, 103.0: 0, 104.0: 0}
  ]
},
{
  key: "person2",
  values:[
  {100.0: 5, 101.0: 0, 102.0: 0, 103.0: 0, 104.0: 0},
  {100.0: 5, 101.0: 0, 102.0: 4, 103.0: 18, 104.0: 12},
  {100.0: 5, 101.0: 0, 102.0: 0, 103.0: 1, 104.0: 0},
  {100.0: 5, 101.0: 1, 102.0: 7, 103.0: 14, 104.0: 21},
  {100.0: 5, 101.0: 0, 102.0: 0, 103.0: 0, 104.0: 0}
  ]
  }
]

let sums = arr.map(({key, values}) => {
  return {
    key,
    values: values.reduce((sums, obj) => {
      Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => sums[k] += obj[k] )
      return sums
    })
  }
})
console.log(sums)
```

If the decimal places are important, you should put quotes around the keys in the you arrays. Otherwise they get converted to strings and loose the the decimals.

Comment: You can shorten `=> {  return { ... }}` to `=> ({...})`